# Superimposing vectors, dgrid3d and pm3d in gnuplot for 3D plot

Tags: vector, plot, 3d, gnuplot, surface

I am trying to plot a vector field in Gnuplot superimposing dgrid3d, pm3d and vectors.
I can get dgrid3d and pm3d to work but when I try to superimpose the vectors weird things happen.

I am trying the following:

```
set dgrid3d 50,50,2
set pm3d at b
set hidden3d
splot 'v-field.dat' u 1:2:6 w l, "" u 1:2:3:4:5:6 w vectors
```

Data is in the format:

```
0.0000000020000000 0.0833272880000000 0 0 0 1.62609277247135e-09
0.5000000020000001 0.5833272880000000 0 0 0 0.965930741599645
0.8749688835000000 0.2083182225000000 0 0 0 0.233003475483508
0.3749688835000000 0.7083182225000000 0 0 0 0.732959928249388
0.7499740065000000 0.3333133385000000 0 0 0 0.612400228894737
0.2499740065000000 0.8333133384999999 0 0 0 0.353562980611359
0.6250021815000000 0.4583253445000000 0 0 0 0.915969987957243
0.1250021814999999 0.9583253445000000 0 0 0 0.0499605601370936
0.2500301575000000 0.0833358625000000 0 0 0 0.183035467628336
0.7500301575000000 0.5833358625000000 0 0 0 0.682946534409448
0.1250311175000000 0.2083182225000000 0 0 0 0.233003477250229
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, I am new to gnuplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `set dgrid3d` and plotting `with vectors` are somehow not compatible. Probably, gnuplot tries to interpolate also for the vectors.
A workaroud would be to plot your interpolated gridded surface into a datablock and then `unset dgrid3d`.
Well, your vectors are hardly visible and when you rotate the graph there is still in issue with depthorder of the surface and the base which I couldn't resolve so far.

**Code:**

```
# combining dgrid3d and vectors
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0000000020000000 0.0833272880000000 0 0 0 1.62609277247135e-09
0.5000000020000001 0.5833272880000000 0 0 0 0.965930741599645
0.8749688835000000 0.2083182225000000 0 0 0 0.233003475483508
0.3749688835000000 0.7083182225000000 0 0 0 0.732959928249388
0.7499740065000000 0.3333133385000000 0 0 0 0.612400228894737
0.2499740065000000 0.8333133384999999 0 0 0 0.353562980611359
0.6250021815000000 0.4583253445000000 0 0 0 0.915969987957243
0.1250021814999999 0.9583253445000000 0 0 0 0.0499605601370936
0.2500301575000000 0.0833358625000000 0 0 0 0.183035467628336
0.7500301575000000 0.5833358625000000 0 0 0 0.682946534409448
0.1250311175000000 0.2083182225000000 0 0 0 0.233003477250229
EOD

set dgrid3d 30,30,2
set pm3d at b 
set hidden3d

set table $Surface
    splot $Data u 1:2:6
unset table

unset dgrid3d

splot $Surface u 1:2:3 w l , \
      $Data u 1:2:3:4:5:6 w vectors lw 2 lc rgb "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, I have more data sets and it looks great in some of my other cases.