# Using gnuplot to plot points with color and x-marks

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have been trying this for a few hours but I am not getting anywhere.
What I am trying to do is this:

I have a solution from a simulation with x and y values and a value for each point.

I am trying to plot the data using gnuplot. I want the values in between my data points to be interpolated using color and the points themself shall be marked with a dot, a "x" or sth. like that similar to this (except for the round border and those labels inside):

[image]

I have been trying to get a very basic example going. My data file looks like this:

```
1   1   0.1
1   2   0.3
1   3   0.6
2   1   0.5
2   2   0.7
2   3   0.9
3   1   0.2
3   2   0.8
3   3   0.7
```

and my gnuplot input like this:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
set output './production/image1.eps'

set palette gray

set title "Titel" 

#set xrange [1:4]
#set yrange [0:10]

set format y "%.1f"
set format x "%.1f"

set xlabel "x-Achse [Einheit]" 
set ylabel "y-Achse [Einheit]" rotate by 90


set view map
set pm3d at b map
set pm3d interpolate 2,2
set dgrid3d 50,50,2
splot "inputDatei.dat" u 1:2:3 linecolor palette
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

There are a few issues with this which i cannot resolve:

1. there is a label in the rip right "inputDatai.dat" u 1:2:3". I tried `splot ... label ""` but this didnt solve the issue
2. the interpolation doesnt seem to work. this is visible with a smaller grid
3. the data points are not highlighted. I tried using `splot ... with points` but this would only display points at EVERY grid corner which is obviously way too much. Also the input data might not be "regular" but points can be anywhere.

I am very happy if someone could help me with this.

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your questions:

1. use `unset key` before the plot command or `splot ... notitle` within the plot command
2. what "does not work" mean? Please explain.
3. I guess that's similar to here ([Superimposing vectors, dgrid3d and pm3d in gnuplot for 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62314778/7295599)). You have to switch off interpolating for the highlighted points. I'm not sure whether this can be done within a plot command, so you have to plot the interpolated data into a separate datablock via `set table` and then switch off interpolation.

**Code:**

```
### interpolate data with highlighted datapoints
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   1   0.1
1   2   0.3
1   3   0.6
2   1   0.5
2   2   0.7
2   3   0.9
2.5 2.5 0.1
3   1   0.2
3   2   0.8
3   3   0.7
EOD

set size square
set view map
set pm3d at b
set pm3d interpolate 2,2
set dgrid3d 50,50,2

set table $DataInterpolated
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 
unset table
unset dgrid3d

set palette grey
set xrange [0.9:3.1]
set yrange [0.9:3.1]

splot $DataInterpolated u 1:2:3 w pm3d palette notitle, \
      $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. About part 2, I thought it would interpolate in between the 50x50 grid but I can just make this grid larger which will have a similar effect